# Which frameworks should I use for Desktop/Touch Angular App which uses USB/Hardware APIs?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, uwp, electron, capacitor

I need to develop an app which relies heavily on **USB/Serial**, [WebAudio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) and potentially other usage of hardware APIs.

At this point, this app is meant only for a **Windows 10 tablet**, so it should also support **touch & gestures**. 
But of course I'll happy to decouple the app logic from Windows/UWP APIs in order to be able to extend the app to many other platforms in the future.

I've chose to wrote this app using **Typescript & Angular**, but really undecided about the framework combination I should use for this purpose:

1) Should I use only pure Electron-Angular-HammerJS combination? (And maybe deploy it [as UWP app](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/windows-store-guide))

2) Should I involve Ionic Framework in order to support touch & mobility better? Or this combination of Electron with Ionic will bloat my app unnecessarily?

3) Does pure Ionic (as UWP app without Electron) support Windows USB/Serial capabilities? I found so far only USB-Cordova plugins for Android...

4) Does Ionic Capacitor serves this app's purpose? On the one hand, this framework tends to support many platforms including Electron, but on the other hand It's core library doesn't include USB/serial API, and even if I'll chose to write generic plugins for hardware usage (like USB) there aren't much documentation about creating Capacitor-Electron-Plugins...

I'll happy to your opinion, because currently I'm very confused & don't know what to choose...

Answer (score -1):

I'll offer a slightly controversial opinion.

If you need to rely on numerous technologies, you need a library for each, because generally you don't want to start reinventing the wheel. For example, for supporting cryptography, I would be looking at a crypto library.

Now, if a particular library advertises itself as a framework, **RUN AWAY!** A framework can and will fight with every other framework in your application. You can have only at most one framework. You need to wrap your entire application around the framework. You can have only 0 or 1 frameworks in your application.

Because of this, my advice would be that the optimal count of frameworks in your application is 0.

Use libraries, don't use frameworks. If a library advertises itself as a framework, don't use it.

Frameworks go out of fashion very quickly. Libraries usually don't go out of fashion as quickly.

Now, of course a particular library can eventually become unmaintained. Thus, I would plan an "exit strategy" for each library. Take a hard look at what kinds of libraries are available. Look at their programming interfaces. Whatever library you choose, create a wrapper around its programming interface, offering the minimal necessary interface for your use case to work. It's essentially the lowest common denominator of all available libraries. If the library becomes unmaintained, you don't rewrite your entire application, you just rewrite the wrapper.

Comment: So, by your purpose - It is better for me to stick with pure Electron & Angular, maybe with combination of Angular-Material - but nothing more than that. For native APIs I'll use DI which require me to implement wrappers for each platform (the first will be electron wrapper which uses Node's USB/Serial library for example)